# Four way message exchange between TCP server and client in java

Tags: java, tcpclient

I am trying to implement a four way message exchange between a TCP client and server wherein server first sends a message, receives reply from client and then again does the same. This can be extended to even more messages. How do I keep the connection open between both of them? If there should be an infinite while loop, where to put it? I tried with this on the client side and got an error. I am not concerned with the server here!

```
// open socket

while(true) {
// read
// send reply
}

clientSocket.close();
```

The problem is that buffer is read twice for the same message sent by the server and then this error results:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at TCPClient.main(TCPClient.java:52)
```

Comment: Show the code where you used those functions

Comment: Surely you realise that the open should be before the loop if the close is after it?

Comment: EJP yeah sure! Its before the while loop. The problem is that the buffer is read again even when it has been processed once! How do I empty the buffer or tell the code that no new msg has been received and the loop should exit now?

Comment: "Handshake" generally refers to *setting up* the connection.  The TCP handshake (SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK) is performed by Java's `open` and `accept` methods.  Once you're passing messages back and forth, the handshake is complete.

Comment: By handshake I meant exchange of data ... title maybe misleading but the question explains the problem I guess!

Comment: No, it didn't read the buffer twice, or give you the same data twice: you have a bug in your code, which you haven't posted. Not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly it is not a TCP Server Handshake but an application specific Layer 7 Handshake. When you connect the socket, 3 way handshake is already performed and socket is connected. What you do on top of it, is just plain exchange of data in a reliable fashion.

So coming back to your question, the exception that is being thrown clearly says that you are not able to write to socket server.

Why? could be multiple reasons:

1. socket server is not behaving the way it should.
2. You are not writing to the socket server e.g after first write, in your loop you might be losing track to socket object and writing to null object, etc.

So elaborate more or just try on yourself, good luck.